# Robust import style in Python with PyCharm

Tags: python, import

I would like my import style to be robust so that scripts can be run through the PyCharm run tool, through the terminal, and in the interactive IPython interpreter. Suppose I have a project that looks like

```
project/
├── module/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── functions.py
│   ├── main.py
```

And suppose that `functions.py` contains a function called `a_function`. In `main.py`, I would like to import with the (in my opinion clearer) absolute import:

```
from module.functions import a_function
```

This works when the code runs in the interactive Python console and in the PyCharm run tool, but not if I run `python module/main.py` from a terminal (`ImportError: No module named 'module'`).

I would like to understand why I get this import error and what would I need to change so that I can keep the import `from module.functions import a_function` and avoid import errors when running `python module/main.py`.

Comment: The directory containing 'module' has to be in your python path.

Comment: Yes, of course, the point is that running through PyCharm and running through the terminal initialize you `sys.path` differently. For now I resorted to adding `sys.path[0] = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.path[0]))` at the beginning of the script, but I'm not very happy with that.